# Paths and Curves with implicit differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $r=r(t)$ and $\theta=\theta(t)$ with $r(t)>0$. Let $x(t)=r(t)\cos(\theta(t))$ and $y(t)=r(t)\sin(\theta(t))$ . Prove that $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(x\frac{dy}{dt}-y\frac{dx}{dt})$

The hint is to use $y(t)/x(t)$ and use implicit differentiation but I can't see how to use that hint to solve this problem.

Comment: you mean cannot

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\frac{y(t)}{x(t)} = \tan(\theta(t)).$$

Now differentiate both sides with respect to $t$. On the left-hand side, you can differentiate $y(t)/x(t)$ using the quotient rule. But on the other side we need to use the chain rule. We have

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \tan(\theta(t)) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta(t))} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$

Now rearrange for $\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}$.